# Change Method from old reference

Tags: .net, http, reference, client

```
public string Post(T obj)
    {
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
        MediaTypeFormatter[] formatter = new MediaTypeFormatter[] { new JsonMediaTypeFormatter() };
        var content = request.CreateContent<T>(obj, MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"), formatter, new FormatterSelector());
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(this.url, content).Result;
        return response.Content.ToString();
    }
```

this is my method Post, that i use in my `HTTPClient`, but there is one problem - `CreateContent` and `FormatterSelector` - is classes from old references. How to rewrite this code to latest references:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

---

I understand in what problem. This methods is extension methods! So they are unavailable to me.

Comment: Add the class that contains the extension methods to your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this piece of code:

```
public async Task<string> Post<T>(T obj)
    {
        MediaTypeFormatter jsonFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
        HttpContent content = new ObjectContent<T>(obj, jsonFormatter);

        var response = await client.PostAsync(this.Url, content);
        return response.Content.ToString();
    }
```